# xcode. swift3. coredata. fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, core-data

I keep getting this error when trying to load an array xputt2 from coreData. When I remove the offending line the data prints perfectly but will not load into the array once I put the line back.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Here is the code.

```
do {
        putt2Array = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print ("results count is", putt2Array.count)


        var i=0
            for record in putt2Array {
                print(record.value(forKeyPath: "missed")! as! Double)
                xputt2[i] = record.value(forKeyPath: "missed")! as! Double
                i += 1
            }

    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("Could not fetch data. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error explains the problem, index is out of range, you are keying into an array at an index that does not yet exist. Try switching

```
xputt2[i] = record.value(forKeyPath: "missed")! as! Double
```

to

```
xputt2.append(record.value(forKeyPath: "missed")! as! Double)
```

You should be able to remove the `i = 0` and incrementing `i`. On a separate note, I would recommend removing the forced unwraps:

```
  for record in putt2Array {
    if let value = record.value(forKeyPath: "missed") as? Double {
      xputt2.append(value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the really useful help which solved the problem perfectly.  I knew it had to be something very simple but I was looking in the wrong place!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

An array's index only goes as far as the number of elements currently in it.  You can use `xputt2[i]` to *replace* an element that already exists, but not to add a new one.  You can either use `xputt2.append` to add it to the end, or `xputt2.insert` if you want to put it at a particular place in the array.

Alternately, since you're just transforming an existing array, you can use the `map` method to do it in a single line:

```
xputt2 = putt2array.map{ $0.value(forKeyPath: "missed")! as! Double }
```